# JavaFx dynamic font change

Tags: java, javafx, fonts

I have this UI in JavaFX:

[image: JavaFX UI]

On selecting a font name from the drop down menu text below should be displayed in a custom font style that I am setting through code like this:

```
fontList.getSelectionModel().
selectedItemProperty() .addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
   @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") 
   @Override 

   public void changed(ObservableValue ov , String oldValue , String newValue) { 

      myText.setText(""); 

      if (newValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Manuscript")) { 
           myText.setFill(Color.RED);
           myText.setFont(Font.loadFont(
              "file:///C:/Program Files/custom/Fonts/SWFNT01A.TTF", 35)); 
           myText.setText("StartWrite Desktop"); 
      } 
});
```

myText is the name of the text field javaFx component. The font file is in my resources folder.

The output is barely legible. At first I thought that since the custom font is not installed that is the reason that the text is so hazy . But after I installed the custom font the text is still hazy and has not changed a bit.

Please tell me what is wrong with this approach.

Comment: `myText.setFont(Font.loadFont("file:path", 120));` try if this changes anything, check also if the file (paht) exists.

Comment: You should add the function where you are including the code you provided too.

Comment: I have tried out the first solution you have provided, it does not help. I cannot understand the second suggestion you have provided .

Comment: the second, i asked you if you could add in your question the function where this code is written

Comment: Have you tried with another font ? Try putting the font in `resources/fonts` of the app project then do this `myText.setFont(Font.loadFont("file:resources/fonts/SWFNT01A.TTF", 120));`. again, be sure this font works in another text editor.

Comment: This is a custom font . I have tried out with other custom fonts but it is not working . It seems the custom  fonts are causing the blurred text.I have put my font files in the resources folder.

Comment: Check in the layout parameters (of the TextField) : LayoutX = 0, LayoutY = 0. All scaling parameters to 1 if this isn't suffiscient check all your parent component layout constraints (AnchorPane or whatever you are using).

Comment: Did change the LayoutX and LayoutY as well as the scaling parameter to 1 as per you suggestion but that does not solve the problem .

Comment: I have found a solution . It works only on text area component , but I can use fonts installed in the system only ie , the font files present in c:\windows\fonts folder. I am trying to find a solution for fonts which are not installed on the system as well . Hope to come up with a solution in a day or two